# is pure c/c++ code possible in webOs intead of javascript?

Tags: webos

HP webOS needs javascript,HTML to develop applications.but is it possible whatever we can do through javascript in c++ or c? have they given any API list for it?I found PDK is for openGL game porting .Have they given any option for C++ developers?

Answer (score 0):

If using C/C++, you are essentially on-your-own when it comes to the interface unless you build a plugin in for a hybrid PDK app that uses HTML and JavaScript for the UI.  You are provided with APIs for system services and accessing the hardware (drawing to the screen, keyboard presses, etc.) in C++.  The intention is that you'll use C/C++ when you need speed, and JavaScript the rest of the time when speed is less critical (as in, you're not doing anything that the user will notice as slower than if you had written the code in C/C++).

To answer the question I sense lies beneath your question, you're probably going to have to learn JavaScript to program for webOS unless you want to develop openGL games only.